# Preserve decimal places in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe, decimal-point

I'm trying to read the excel worksheet to DataFrame using pd.read_excel() function. I want to check if each element in the FX column contains 2 decimals and are displayed with 2 decimals. Actually all elements in the FX Rate column have 2 decimals, but some of them are displayed with no decimal.

[image: content in excel worksheet]

I tried to use the following command to transfer the data type of FX column to str.

```
fx_forward = pd.read_excel(io = file_path, sheet_name = "FX Rate", dtype = {"FX Rate" :str})
```

I expect to get a DataFrame looks like this:

[image: expected output]

However, I get a DataFrame whose FX Rate are all "1".

[image]

What should I do to get the expected DataFrame?

Comment: Check the format of your cells. If Pandas only shows you 1s (without decimals, with dtype str), it's because the cells only contain 1s. Pandas is not sensitive to cell format.

Comment: Hi Corralien, thanks for your answer. So if I want to keep the format I should better not use pandas?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the reason for that is that you are declaring the dtype as `str` and the values do not actualy holds the decimals, and excel just shows them.

I've created an excel similar to the one you mentioned and have the results with 2 decimal points as follows

```
import pandas as pd

# Set the default pandas float print format to show 2 decimal points
pd.set_option("display.float_format", '{:,.2f}'.format)

df = pd.read_excel(io = file_path, sheet_name = 'FX Rate', dtype = {'FX Rate': float})

df.head()
```

The results:

```
       ID  FX Rate
0  TRADE1     1.00
1  TRADE2     1.00
2  TRADE3     1.00
3  TRADE4     1.00
4  TRADE5     1.00
```

Comment: Hi Saar, thanks for your response. Is it possible that I can have some elements in the FX Rate shown as "1.00" and some of them as "1", just the same as the excel?